# Dynamic `named_scope` depending on certain criterias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

dear all, i have a `Student` model that i've specified some `name_scope` in it, e.g. `from_program`, `from_year`, `from_school`, `has_status`, `from_course`, etc...

is there anyway that i can chain the different `named_scope` together dynamically depending on certain criterias during runtime?

for example, if the user accessing the data is from Finance, i want to be able to chain `from_school` and `has_status` together only. if the user is the lecturer, i want to be able to chain `from_course`, `from_school` together, and so on...

should i use `named_scope`? or should i just fall back to the good old way of specifying conditions?

thanks for your suggestions in advance! =) btw i'm using rails 2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understood, but I think you could do something like this:

```
class Student

  named_scope from_program, lambda{|program| :conditions => {:program => program}}
  named_scope from_year, lambda{|year| :conditions => {:year => year}}
  named_scope has_status, lambda{|status| :conditions => {:status => status}}

  def self.from_finance(school, status)
    self.from_school(school).has_status(status)
  end

end
```

or more general

```
def self.get_students(params)
  scope = self
  [:program, :year, :school, :course].each do |s|
    scope = scope.send("from_#{s}", params[s]) if params[s].present?
  end
  scope = scope.has_status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  scope
end
```

Comment: yeah you get what i need to achieve, but your general case isn't getting the result because when you do a `send`, the `named_scope` runs immediately, thus it's not chaining all the named_scopes together =( i try to avoid the first method as the criterias can get very fine as they are allowed to specify what group of students they wish to retrieve based on the scopes alr allowed... =( but thanks for your suggestion though, very close!

Comment: you're welcome! ;] About general method: I've tested it and for combined named scopes (added by the name or by send) it is still ok, producing only 1 query... I have an app where I used this approach and if I do in console _Order.send(:edited).send(:by_code, 3)_ I get  _Order Load (0.3ms) SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE ((code LIKE '%3%') AND (`orders`.`status` = 'edition'))_

Comment: i've tried running using this way, but it didn't return any results, it just return the Student class itself...

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
  Class User extend ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :semester

  named_scope :year, lambda { |*year|
    if year.empty? || year.first.nil?
      { :joins => :semester, :conditions => ["year = #{CURRENT_SEMESTER}"]}
    else
      { :joins => :semester, :conditions => ["year = #{year}"]}
    end
    }

  end
```

You can call like this

```
  User.year     # defaults to CURRENT_SEMESTER constant
  User.year()  # same as above
  User.year(nil)  # same as above; useful if passing a param value that may or may not exist, ie, param[:year]
  User.year(2010)
```

In the same way you can pass parameters

Comment: this is not what i asked actually... but thanks for the suggestion